# Cast to ObjectId failed for value "xxx" at path "_id" when aggregating with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am trying to use aggregation based on my mongoose model. I want to aggregate amounts based on categoryId. But when trying to access via routes url, I am getting this error. (Cast to ObjectId failed for value "test" at path "_id").

my mongoose model in test.js (MODEL)

```
var ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var test = new Schema({
    //testId:ObjectId,
    testName: String,
    amount:Number,
    categoryId:String
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('test', test);
```

My controller testController -

```
var Test = require('../models/test');
function aggTest(req,res){
    Test.aggregate([{
        $group:{
            _id:"$categoryId",
            totalAmount:{$sum: "$amount"}
        }
    }],function(err,result){
        console.log(result);
    });
}
```

Routes mapping

```
router.get('/test',testController.aggTest);
```

Error that-

```
{
  message: "Cast to ObjectId failed for value "test" at path "_id""
  name: "CastError"
  type: "ObjectId"
  value: "test"
  path: "_id"
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could it be because the aggregation pipeline takes 2 parameters `$match` and `$group`? I have no problem using mongoose to aggregate stuff with a `wherecondition`

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/aggregation-zip-code-data-set/

as per the examples given here, they have used $group without $match

Comment: That error is very "mongoose specific", so I suspect you are not showing code. I think you are trying to "cast" your aggregation results into Mongoose objects. The `.aggregate()` command itself just returns "plain objects". That makes sense because "usually" your result object from aggregation looks nothing like the model for the original collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were 2 issues in my answer. Thanks for Blake Seven for pointing me in to the right direction. I didn't have a proper return to return response and my callback function was not correct.
The corrected code is here.

```
Test.aggregate([
        { $group: {
            _id:"$categoryId",
            totalAmount:{$sum: "$amount"}
        }}
    ], function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        console.log(result);
        res.json({ data:result });
    });
```